# Buttons in linear layout are uneven due to font size

Tags: android, button, alignment, android-linearlayout

I try to fit 4 buttons in linear layout. When I set larger font size of 4th button other buttons moves down whereas I want them to be on top.

[image: buttons are not aligned]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingStart="23dp"
    android:paddingEnd="22dp"
    android:paddingTop="25dp"
    android:paddingBottom="59dp"
    android:background="#F1F3F6 "
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textAppearance="@style/app_name_style" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/panel_style"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/sample_text"
            android:textColor="#546E7A"
            android:textSize="40sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:gravity="top">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            style="@style/white_button"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/button_ac"
            android:textSize="29sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="@style/white_button"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/button_plus_minus"
            android:textSize="29sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            style="@style/white_button"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/button_percent"
            android:textSize="29sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            style="@style/blue_button"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/button_divide"
            android:textSize="43sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textSize="43sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In the `styles` file I just set a couple of settings for buttons like `textColor`, `fontFamily`, `shape of button` and etc.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="white_button_text_appearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">#3A4E89</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/montserrat_bold</item>
    </style>

    <style name="white_button">
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/white_button_style</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/white_button_text_appearance</item>
    </style>

    <style name="blue_button_text_appearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/montserrat_bold</item>
    </style>

    <style name="blue_button">
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/blue_button_style</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/blue_button_text_appearance</item>
    </style>

    <style name="app_name_style">
        <item name="android:textSize">28sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#373A37</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/museo700</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

`android:gravity="top"` doesn't work (this can be seen in the second linear layout with standard buttons):

Comment: Set `android:baselineAligned="false"` on the `<LinearLayout>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I struggled with this all day, and the solution was so simple.